# Array alignment with different linkers

Tags: c, linker, embedded, gnu, linker-scripts

I'm working on a big embedded project and I'm facing an issue that I cannot explain with my limited knowledge of linkers.
I've managed to recreate the problem in a really simple program.

I have a single C source file and I want to align an array to a 16 kB boundary, but I don't want to do that with the *aligned* attribute. Instead, I want to use ALIGN builtin function of the linker script.

The source file is pretty simple:

```
#include "boot.h"

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

uint8_t boo[0x800] __attribute__ (( section(".data_aligned") )) = { 0U };

uint8_t foo[0x800] = { 1U };

void start()
{
    return;
}
```

And the linker script is:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x00100000 ;

    _sCode = . ;

    .text ALIGN(0x1000) : { *(.text) }

    .data ALIGN(0x1000) :
    {
        _sData = . ;
        *(.data) ;
        _eData = . ;
        . = ALIGN(0x4000) ;
        _sDataAlign = . ;
        *(.data_aligned) ;
        _eDataAlign = . ;
    }

    .rodata ALIGN(0x1000) : { *(.rodata) }
    
    .bss ALIGN(0x1000) : { *(.bss) }
    
    _eCode = . ;
    
}
```

I compiled and linked the project with gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) with these commands:

```
gcc -c -masm=att -m32 -nostdinc -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-pic -std=c99 -o bin/boot.o boot.c
ld -e 0x100000 bin/boot.o -T linker_script_gcc.ld -m elf_i386 --verbose -O0 -o bin/application.elf
```

From the elf file I get:

```
     ...
     8: 00101000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _sData
     2: 00101000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 
    13: 00101000  2048 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 foo
    10: 00101800     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _eData
    14: 00104000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _sDataAlign
     7: 00104000  2048 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 boo
     9: 00104800     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _eDataAlign
    ...
```

It seems that the *boo* array has been succesfully aligned to the 16 kB boundary.

However, when this program is compiled with the GHS compiler, the *boo* array is not aligned as expected:

```
    ...
    26: 00101000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _sData
     6: 00101000 18432 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 .data
    22: 00101000  2048 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 foo
    27: 00101800     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _eData
    28: 00105000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _sDataAlign
    21: 00105000  2048 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 boo
    29: 00105800     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 _eDataAlign
    ...
```

So I wondered what really should be the value of *_sDataAlign* and why.

According to the documentation [linked here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Location-Counter.html#Location-Counter), the location counter in a linker script is relative to the start of the output section in which is evaluated:

> Note: . actually refers to the byte offset from the start of the current containing object. Normally this is the SECTIONS statement, whose start address is 0, hence . can be used as an absolute address. If . is used inside a section description however, it refers to the byte offset from the start of that section, not an absolute address.

Moreover, [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Expression-Section.html#Expression-Section) it is explained:

> Unary operations on a relative address, and binary operations on two relative addresses in the same section or between one relative address and a number, apply the operator to the offset part of the address(es).

And:

> The result of other operations on relative addresses (after above conversions) is a relative address in the same section as the operand(s).

So, in my understanding, the symbol *_sDataAlign* is set to 0x4000 relative to the start of the .data section which is 0x101000. Therefore, *_sDataAlign* should be 0x105000, exactly as computed by the GHS compiler.

Is this analysis correct? If so, why GNU linker is giving me a wrong value?

Comment: Does your GHS actually support the __attribute__(()) stuff? This was introduced by GCC and then taken by CLANG, but not all compilers might support that.

Comment: Yes, according to the manual, my GHS supports the __attribute__ keyword and specifically it supports the section attribute. Indeed, the *boo* array is correctly placed after the *_sDataAlign* symbol where the section .data_aligned is placed.

Comment: BTW, if you have problems with the GHS, why are you pasting here excerpts from the GNU linker and not the one from the GHS linker?

Comment: Because, after my analysis explained in the question, I definitely agree with the value calculated by the GHS linker and NOT with the one calculated by the GNU linker...